# Windows Application: Switching to iframe window nested inside the same window

Tags: java, windows, selenium-webdriver, winappdriver, appium-desktop

Firstly, I have tried `driver.switchTo().frame("framename");` but it does not switching to that.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("xxx");/// Throws an {"status":7,"value":{"error":"no such element","message":"An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters."}}
```

After dig into deeper, I found that the particular frame locators were not even present inside the page source. Any idea on how to switch to that frame.

P.S. I'm using WinApp driver.

Note: Same scenario in web, I'm able to switch using switchTo iframe elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a mismatch here. What you need to input at frame(" ") is not a string. It should be:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath of the iframe"));
```

Comment: Even after giving a xpath, It doesn't switching to the frame. Because in page source iframe elements were not there. So it throws no such element in it.